# Create Population Density map in Tableau

Tags: python, maps, tableau-api, matplotlib-basemap, density-plot

I have compiled an excel sheet containing the taluka(sub-district) names, latitudes & longitudes, and population.

I want to create a heat map such that the areas with higher populations appear brighter than others.

However when I select the density mark type, it forms a heat map with closer points(cluster of points) appearing brighter.

I then tried adding the population to the size but it is disabled when I choose the density mark.

Am attaching the link to sample workbook and the compiled excel data:
[Gujarat Workbook.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16wwaYjH54KXS0Nt_pVh58WMPa1jacvmf?usp=sharing)
Alternatively, can this(Creating a population density map) be done in python?

Comment: Two questions: does your data also contain the *area* of each region (you need this to calculate pop density)? do you have a spatial file with the *shapes* of each area (tableau doesn't always have the built in maps fo the regions you want)?

Comment: No Matt, I do not have the spatial and area data. I am trying to create an approximate heat map by overlaying multiple circles(Sized by population of each sub-district) on top of each other so that I get a bright color on that spot.

Comment: You need at least some spatial data to plot anything (lat/lons might work but only if they are the geographic or population centroids of the areas) and you need the area data to calculate population density. Tableau can't magically create data you don't have.

Comment: All I am asking for is a way to change the intensity of overlapped circles(plotted by lat/long coordinates and sized by population, both of which I have). I am considering that the co-ordinates are the centroids. I do not expect Tableau to magically create anything.

Comment: Then use the colour control to set a low opacity for the colour of the circles and, when they overlap, the result will be darker. But this isn't a reliable way to generate your intended result.